# Interrupt queue or file write operation in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, javax.imageio

I work with large images on the iPhone, so saving them to disk can take several seconds, and sometimes an instruction to delete the image comes when it hasn't finished saving. I would like to interrupt the saving process and delete the file inmediatly, without waiting for it to save first, but I can't find any way to interrupt the queue or the saving operation.

```
@interface YMSavedImage : NSObject {
    UIImage *image;
    NSString *path;
    dispatch_queue_t imageAccess;
    ...
}
@end

@implementation YMSavedImage

- (id)init
{
    ...
    imageAccess = dispatch_queue_create("imageAccessQueue", NULL);
    ...
}

- (void)save
{
    dispatch_async(imageAccess, ^(void) {
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];  // This takes several seconds.
    });
}

- (void)delete
{
    dispatch_sync(imageAccess, ^(void) {
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
        }
    });
}

...

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`writeToFile:atomically:` is going to want to write all of the data to file in one shot. You would be better off grabbing an `NSFileHandle` and quickly writing subsections of the data, after each atomic write you could check to see if the user has requested to cancel saving.

I'd suggest something like:

```
- (void)save 
{
    dispatch_async(imageAccess, ^{

        // Create an empty file to populate
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:_imageFilePath contents:nil attributes:nil];

        // Grab a handle on the file
        NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:_imageFilePath];

        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image);

        // Store how long the image is
        NSUInteger totalLength = [imageData length];

        // Store how many chunks we should need with the set kDesiredChunkSize
        NSUInteger chunks = totalLength / kDesiredChunkSize;

        NSUInteger i = 0;

        // Walk through the image chunk by chunk and check if we are cancelled after each atomic operation
        for (i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
            [handle seekToEndOfFile];
            [handle writeData:[imageData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i * kDesiredChunkSize, kDesiredChunkSize)]];

            if (__userCancelledSave) { // The user asked us to cancel,
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:_imageFilePath error:nil]; // FIXME: Handle this error
                return;
            }
        }

        // Write any remaining data that's less than one chunk in size
        NSUInteger sizeDifference = totalLength - (chunks * kDesiredChunkSize);

        if (sizeDifference > 0) {
            [handle seekToEndOfFile];
            [handle writeData:[imageData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(chunks * kDesiredChunkSize, sizeDifference)]];
        }
    });
}
```